# Magento - Change Top Link Label of existing link (login link)

Tags: magento

The default magento template has a top link called "Login".
This is being output by the standard template customer.xml.

I did this in my local.xml, hoping to remove the current link "Login" and by readding the same link but with a different label "Login / Register"

```
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl" /></action>
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In / Register</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
```

However now i have 2 links there displaying, one called "Login" and another called "Login / Register".

How can i properly change the label of a toplink in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to remove

```
 <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
            </action>
        </reference>
     </default>
```

add by this

```
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Log In / Register</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLogInUrl"/>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
        </action>
    </reference>
```